# Problema con area.addText(char...) JAVA

Tags: java, string, sublimetext3

Intento leer un archivo desde java, y añadirlo a un JTextArea:

```
    if (e.getSource() == go) {
        try {
            String strA = field1.getText();
            FileReader archr1 = new FileReader(strA);
            int valor = archr1.read();

            while(valor!=-1) {
                System.out.print((char)valor);
                area1.setText((char)valor);
                valor = archr1.read();
            } //fin while

            archr1.close();

        } catch(IOException r) {
            area1.setText("Error: "+r);
        } // fin catch
    }
```

Para comprobar que me lee el archivo, uso el print (char)valor y si que me muestra todo el contenido.

Pero al añadirlo al JTextArea (area1) me devuelve este error:

```
"error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String"
```

Como podría convertir en un String el resultado final, para que pueda mostrarme en el textarea el contenido?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba esto:

```
if (e.getSource() == go) {
        try {
            String strA = field1.getText();
            FileReader archr1 = new FileReader(strA);
            int valor = archr1.read();
            String miString = "";
        while(valor!=-1) {
           System.out.print((char)valor);
           char miChar = (char)valor;
           miString += Character.toString(miChar);
            valor = archr1.read();
        } //fin while
        area1.setText(miString);
        archr1.close();

    } catch(IOException r) {
        area1.setText("Error: "+r);
    } // fin catch
}
```

Comment: Esto lo he probado antes, en la consola, me lee el archivo perfectamente, y en el jtextarea, me aperece: -1 aun que no entiendo el porque me coje ese valor (que lo saca del while si no me equivoco)

Comment: Le has realizado un toString() al char, a ver si te funciona?

Comment: Donde exactamente le hago el toString ?

Comment: Edite la respuesta, checkeala

Comment: Me devuelve: error: char cannot be dereferenced en: String miString = miChar.toString();

Comment: La acabo de editar otra vez, perdona, que no vi el fallo al principio

Comment: Pruebala de nuevo

Comment: Ahora me devuelve por lo visto el último caracter, un paso hemos avanzado ya jajaja

Comment: jajajaja. Prueba de nuevo

Comment: Ostras cojonudo, ahora si, para quedarme a mi claro: miString + = Character.toString(miChar); esta es la clave si no me equivoco, dentro del while recoje todas las letras, ya fuera del while, podemos mostrar todo el contenido dentro del string

Comment: Si señor. miString + = Character.toString(miChar); va creando la cadena para despues, fuera del while mostrarla entera.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!